# Looping through two objects in a Django template

Tags: python, django

I have an app objects and image objects which are linked to one another (the apps have images).

```
def index(request):
    latest_apps_list = App.objects.all().exclude(approved=False).order_by('name')[:20]
    app_images = Image.objects.filter(app__in=latest_apps_list).order_by('app__name')[:20]
    t = loader.get_template('apps/index.html')
    c = Context({
        'latest_apps_list': latest_apps_list,
        'app_images': app_images
    })
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

Now I want to loop through those images in my template. How would I do that with **both** variables? I tried using zip(), but this returned mysql errors as it calls for unsupported db queries. Is there another way?

Currently I have:

```
{% for app in latest_apps_list %}

...{{ app.name }}

{% endfor %}
```

This works. Of course, it doesn't return the images urls. (I'm using sorl-thumbnail btw.)

**UPDATE** Perhaps I'm just going about doing this the wrong way. Here's how I have my **model**:

```
class App(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    # ...

class Image(models.Model):
   app = models.ForeignKey(App)
   image = models.ImageField(upload_to = "apps")
```

And my **view** is in the original part of the post above. It seems like I should somehow be making the app's properties and the image properties all one thing, without the need to zip in the view. Is this possible?

**UPDATE 2** I solved this by greatly simplifying how the model is created. Here's what I did in case anyone else is trying to do this.

**apps/admin.py**: the image object is included as an ordinary field.

```
class AppAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   fieldsets = [
      ('Basic', {'fields':['name','desc','price','approved','image']}),
      ('Author',        {'fields':['docs_url', 'preview_url']}),
   ]
   list_display = ('name', 'desc', 'price', 'approved')


admin.site.register(App, AppAdmin)
```

**apps/models.py**: Just make image part of the app itself. No foreign keys needed.

```
class App(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    # ...
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = "apps")
```

**apps/views.py**: Now the view just has one object to loop through. No weird sql queries needed.

```
def index(request):
    latest_apps_list = App.objects.all().exclude(approved=False).order_by('name')[:20]
    t = loader.get_template('apps/index.html')
    c = Context({
        'latest_apps_list': latest_apps_list,
    })
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

Comment: how did you use "zip"? Did you try converting querysets to lists before it? Try doing: `zip(list(latest_apps_list),list(app_images))`.

Be careful! This is correct if both lists have the same length. Otherwise, you will have an undesired behavior....

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it just gave me an error page. "The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request."

Comment: Does iterating through only the images work?  `{% for image in app_images %}` ...

Comment: So it looks like the problem is in those two definitions for latest_apps_list and app_images...

Comment: "The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request." -- That's not a useful error page; turn on DEBUG in your settings and you will see what the *actual* error is when an exception is thrown.

Comment: I do have debug on. In this case, Django is unable to even return a stack trace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should zip them in the view, and pass that zipped object to the template, and then iterate through them.

view:

```
def index(request):
    latest_apps_list = list(App.objects.all().exclude(approved=False).order_by('name')[:20])
    app_images = Image.objects.filter(app__in=latest_apps_list).order_by('app__name')[:20]
    t = loader.get_template('apps/index.html')
    c = Context({
        'zipped_app_list': zip(latest_apps_list, list(app_images))
    })
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

template:

```
{% for app, image in zipped_app_list %}
    {{ app }}
    {{ image}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yeah, this causes me to get the same error from the start: (1235, "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'")

Comment: which mysql are you using, and which django version?

Comment: From the terminal: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.16, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Comment: it happens because you gave a queryset parameter to filter: latest_apps_list (I just copied the code) but it can't accept querysets.

Comment: of course, now the updated query doesn't seem very efficient, I'm not sure about how your db scheme looks like, but it would be better surely if you set a ForeignKey on the Image table, which points on App and give it a related_name, and then access the image through it.

Comment: Try using izip as well, rather than zip; it won't be forced to evaluate both results sets and keep the entire zipped result in memory

Comment: Thanks, @IanClelland, though as user65... discovered, it looks like the problem is in the app_images definition and not the zipping itself.